# Mount storage from Fiber Channel SAN on Oracle Linux

Tags: linux, mount, storage, oracle-linux, san

I have a scenario where my shared storage is available at SAN (Storage Area Network). The SAN is available through Fiber Channel. I am installing some oracle product and want to use storage from SAN only. The problem I am facing regarding 'mount' of location from SAN to my Linux machine. Attached the screenshot. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Before mounting the SAN storage on your virtual machine, you'll need to present the storage to the VM(s). There are two ways to do it:

A. present the entire 1250 GiB LUN as a single device to a single VM or to a cooperating cluster of VMs.

***or***

B. initialize the LUN as Oracle VM storage repository, then use that repository in creating any number virtual disks for any number of VMs.

---

As you can see, option B is more flexible, but option A may offer more performance and may be simpler to implement if you just need a big chunk of storage to a single VM.

If you choose option A, you'll need to go to the settings of the VM that needs the storage, on the Disks tab, pick an empty slot, switch the slot from "Empty" to "Physical Disk", then select the LUN to be presented for the VM.

Then you can login to the VM and perform the necessary initialization steps, just like with any other new disk: you may want to partition the disk and/or initialize it with `pvcreate` for use with LVM. If you use LVM, then you can either create a new VG or add the new PV to an existing VG, and then create or extend logical volumes as needed. Once the partition(s) or new LV(s) are ready, the next step is to create filesystem(s) on them. Only after that you can mount them.

If you choose option B, there's a bit more work within the OVM Manager: you should first go to the Repositories tab, and set up the SAN LUN as an OVM repository. Then you can go to the settings of the VM that needs the storage, on the Disks tab, then pick an empty slot, switch its type to "Virtual Disk", click on the green + icon to create a new virtual disk, specify the repository, size and name for the new virtual disk, and whether the virtual disk should be "shared" or not, i.e. whether it should be usable by more than one VM simultaneously or not. Once you've done this, the new virtual disk gets presented to the VM: the next step is to log into the VM and initialize it for use, just like with option A.